# raw, weak_ptr, unique_ptr, shared_ptr etc... How to choose them wisely?

Tags: c++, programming-practices, pointers, qt, smart-pointer

There is a lot of pointers in C++ but to be honest in 5 years or so in C++ programming (specifically with the Qt Framework) I only use the old raw pointer:

```
SomeKindOfObject *someKindOfObject = new SomeKindOfObject();
```

I know there are a lot of other "smart" pointers:

```
// shared pointer:
shared_ptr<SomeKindofObject> Object;

// unique pointer:
unique_ptr<SomeKindofObject> Object;

// weak pointer:
weak_ptr<SomeKindofObject> Object;
```

But I don't have the slightest idea of what to do with them and what they can offer me in comparison of raw pointers.

For example I have this class header:

```
#ifndef LIBRARY
#define LIBRARY

class LIBRARY
{
public:
    // Permanent list that will be updated from time to time where
    // each items can be modified everywhere in the code:
    QList<ItemThatWillBeUsedEveryWhere*> listOfUselessThings; 
private:
    // Temporary reader that will read something to put in the list
    // and be quickly deleted:
    QSettings *_reader;
    // A dialog that will show something (just for the sake of example):
    QDialog *_dialog;
};

#endif
```

This is clearly not exhaustive but for each of these 3 pointers is it OK to leave them "raw" or should I use something more appropriate?

And in the second time, if an employer will read the code, will he be strict on what kind of pointers I use or not?

Comment: This topic seems so appropriate for SO. [this was in 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one/106614#106614). And here's [Which kind of pointer do I use when?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706192/which-kind-of-pointer-do-i-use-when?lq=1). I'm sure you can find even better matches. These were just the first I saw

Comment: imo this one's borderline since it's as much about the conceptual meaning/intent of these classes as it is about the technical details of their behavior and implementations. Since the accepted answer leans toward the former, I'm happy with having this be the "PSE version" of that SO question.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

A "raw" pointer is **unmanaged.** That is, the following line:

```
SomeKindOfObject *someKindOfObject = new SomeKindOfObject();
```

... will leak memory if an accompanying `delete` is not executed at the proper time.

#### `auto_ptr`

In order to minimize these cases, [`std::auto_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) was introduced. Due to the limitations of C++ prior to the 2011 standard, however, it's still very easy for `auto_ptr` to leak memory. It is sufficient for limited cases, such as this, however:

```
void func() {
    std::auto_ptr<SomeKindOfObject> sKOO_ptr(new SomeKindOfObject());
    // do some work
    // will not leak if you do not copy sKOO_ptr.
}
```

One of its weakest use-cases is in containers. This is because if a copy of an `auto_ptr<>` is made and the old copy is not carefully reset, then the container may delete the pointer and lose data.

#### `unique_ptr`

As a replacement, C++11 introduced [`std::unique_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
void func2() {
    std::unique_ptr<SomeKindofObject> sKOO_unique(new SomeKindOfObject());

    func3(sKOO_unique); // now func3() owns the pointer and sKOO_unique is no longer valid
}
```

Such a `unique_ptr<>` will be correctly cleaned up, even when it's passed between functions. It does this by semantically representing "ownership" of the pointer - the "owner" cleans it up. This makes it ideal for use in containers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeKindofObject>> sKOO_vector();
```

Unlike `auto_ptr<>`, `unique_ptr<>` is well-behaved here, and when the `vector` resizes, none of the objects will be accidentally deleted while the `vector` copies its backing store.

#### `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`

`unique_ptr<>` is useful, to be sure, but there are cases where you want two parts of your code base to be able to refer to the same object and copy the pointer around, while still being guaranteed proper cleanup. For example, a tree might look like this, when using [`std::shared_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

```
template<class T>
struct Node {
    T value;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> left;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> right;
};
```

In this case, we can even hold on to multiple copies of a root node, and the tree will be properly cleaned up when all copies of the root node are destroyed.

This works because each `shared_ptr<>` holds on to not only the pointer to the object, but also a reference count of all of the `shared_ptr<>` objects that refer to the same pointer. When a new one is created, the count goes up. When one is destroyed, the count goes down. When the count reaches zero, the pointer is `delete`d.

So this introduces a problem: Double-linked structures end up with circular references. Say we want to add a `parent` pointer to our tree `Node`:

```
template<class T>
struct Node {
    T value;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> parent;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> left;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> right;
};
```

Now, if we remove a `Node`, there's a cyclic reference to it. It'll never be `delete`d because its reference count will never be zero.

To solve this problem, you use a [`std::weak_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr):

```
template<class T>
struct Node {
    T value;
    std::weak_ptr<Node<T>> parent;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> left;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> right;
};
```

Now, things will work correctly, and removing a node will not leave stuck references to the parent node. It makes walking the tree a little more complicated, however:

```
std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> parent_of_this = node->parent.lock();
```

This way, you can lock a reference to the node, and you have a reasonable guarantee it won't disappear while you're working on it, since you're holding on to a `shared_ptr<>` of it.

#### `make_shared` and `make_unique`

Now, there are some minor problems with `shared_ptr<>` and `unique_ptr<>` that should be addressed. The following two lines have a problem:

```
foo_unique(std::unique_ptr<SomeKindofObject>(new SomeKindOfObject()), thrower());
foo_shared(std::shared_ptr<SomeKindofObject>(new SomeKindOfObject()), thrower());
```

If `thrower()` throws an exception, both lines will leak memory. And more than that, `shared_ptr<>` holds the reference count far away from the object it points to and this *can* mean a second allocation). That's not usually desirable.

C++11 provides [`std::make_shared<>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) and C++14 provides [`std::make_unique<>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) to solve this problem:

```
foo_unique(std::make_unique<SomeKindofObject>(), thrower());
foo_shared(std::make_shared<SomeKindofObject>(), thrower());
```

Now, in both cases, even if `thrower()` throws an exception, there will not be a leak of memory. As a bonus, `make_shared<>()` has the opportunity to create its reference count *in the same memory space* as its managed object, which can both be faster and can save a few bytes of memory, while giving you an exception safety guarantee!

### Notes about Qt

It should be noted, however, that Qt, which must support pre-C++11 compilers, has its own garbage-collection model: Many `QObject`s have a mechanism where they will be destroyed properly without the need for the user to `delete` them.

I do not know how `QObject`s will behave when managed by C++11 managed pointers, so I can not say that `shared_ptr<QDialog>` is a good idea. I do not have enough experience with Qt to say for sure, but I *believe* that Qt5 has been adjusted for this use case.

Comment: @Zilators: Please note my added comment about Qt. The answer to your question about whether all three pointers should be managed depends on whether Qt objects will behave well.

Comment: "both make separate allocation to hold the pointer"? No, unique_ptr never allocates anything extra, only shared_ptr must allocate a reference-count+allocator-object. "both lines will leak memory"? no, only might, not even a guarantee of bad behavior.

Comment: @Deduplicator: My wording must have been unclear: The `shared_ptr` is a separate object - a separate allocation - from the `new`ed object. They exist in different locations. `make_shared` has the ability to put them together at the same location, which improves cache locality, among other things.

Comment: @greyfade: Nononono. `shared_ptr` is an object. And to manage an object, it must allocate a (reference-counts (weak+strong) + destroyer)-object. `make_shared` allows allocating that and the managed object as one piece. `unique_ptr` does not use those, thus there's no corresponding advantage, aside from making sure the object is always owned by the smart-pointer. As an aside, one can have a `shared_ptr` which *owns* an underlying object and represents a `nullptr`, or which does not own and represents a non-nullpointer.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I've made a relevant edit. Please correct it if it's still wrong.

Comment: I looked at it, and there seems to be a general confusion about what a `shared_ptr` does: 1. It shares ownership of some object (represented by an internal dynamically-allocated object having a weak and a strong reference count, as well as a deleter). 2. It contains a pointer. Those two parts are independent. `make_unique` and `make_shared` both make sure the allocated object is put safely  into a smart-pointer. In addition, `make_shared` allows allocating the ownership-object and the managed pointer together.

Comment: Nice overview. Minor detail: I think you mean "stuck cyclic reference" instead of "tangling/dangling pointer". A "dangling pointer" is one that points to data that had been deleted or moved away.

Comment: This post is completely incorrect with respect to auto_ptr. It doesn't leak all that easily, nor is the main concern with putting them in a standard container the possibility of double free. auto_ptr transfers ownership on copy construction or copy assignment; it's like if a unique_ptr implicitly used std::move on itself. The concern with putting it in a container is that standard containers could accidentally destroy elements, because they assumed standard copy semantics. Would be helpful if you corrected your answer.

Comment: I haven't used Qt5 yet, but in Qt4 I found it best practice to not mix STL and Qt facilities - in fact when using Qt you don't need STL at all, except at interfaces to external STL-based modules. Qt brings its own set of smart pointers, and you're well advised to use them with Qt objects as well as your own classes. Of course there may be special cases, but I would count them as optimization, and you should have a very good reason to break this basic rule.

Comment: Note that auto_ptr has been fully removed in C++17